# Sql Access Convert String Date (Year) to Integer

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having a criteria error mistmatch. I think that is because I'm comparing a string and a integer > 08

```
SELECT * FROM [Data]
WHERE [A] <> 'NULL'  AND RIGHT([A], 2)='08';
```

Ok I select all the table content and and need to compare the last 2 digits of a string with the format 10-May-15 I only want to show the 09 or higher dates. I tried convert and Cast with no luck :| NOTE: The code above is showing = and not > because I was testing it. So what I need is

```
SELECT * FROM [Data]
    WHERE [A] <> 'NULL'  AND RIGHT([A], 2) > 09;
```

But for this to work I need a way to convert this from string to integer.
I tried CONVERT and Access does not recognize it :|

Comment: First you try to get what the RIGHT statement is giving you by writing, `select RIGHT([A], 2) FROM [Data]` and check whether the result if its '08' then first statement will work or if its 8 then second statement will work, and the condition need to be changed `RIGHT([A], 2) > 09` to `RIGHT([A], 2) > 9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the field is a string, this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM [Data]
WHERE RIGHT([A], 2) > '09';
```

and this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Data]
WHERE RIGHT([A], 2) > 9;
```

If the field is a date, this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM [Data]
WHERE YEAR([A]) > 9;
```

Comment: Thanks I got it to work erasing the <> 'NULL' is weird because that code works but it gives error with this new way. Anyways I just change the Null string to "" and now do the search well. Thanks for both guys :)

Comment: You would use: where [A] is not null .... better it is moot here as the second condition excludes null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract day, month or year from datetime string. See following example in sql server.

```
  declare @date as date = '10-May-15'
    select DAY(@date)
    select YEAR(@date)
    select MONTH(@date)
```

The results will be

- 10
- 2015
- 5

In your case just use

```
SELECT * FROM [Data]
WHERE YEAR([A]) > 09;
```

I've assumed that you want to get the Year part and compare.

Comment: Is a great idea but I'm still getting the same Criteria Error

Comment: @user3171557 What do you mean by criteria error. Could you please provide more background details about the scenario you are working with ?

Comment: Using the same code as above in Access 2013 give the error "Data type Mismatch in criteria expression" :(

Comment: @user3171557 Ok. I've got it. Problem is come up with 'NULL' checking part. Not with the latter part of the where clause. omit the null checking part and check it again. It should be working. I've already tested it. I'll edit my answer above.


P.S. you don't need to check for null actually. If there are null value for your column [A] those records will be filtered with yaer([A]) > 09 part of the where clause. 

Please let me know if this is working. :)